# Remove text field value in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

when i click on add it show the text field with value. And when i click on remove its hide. But i want to remove text field value also when i click on remove.

Css

```
#second {
    display: none;
}
#third {
    display: none;
}
#forth {
    display: none;
}
#fifth {
    display: none;
}
```

html

```
<div id="header">
     <a href="#" id="add1">add</a> - <a href="#" id="remove">remove</a>
    <div id="first" class="toggle"><input type="text" value="1" name="sid[]">first</div>            
    <div id="second" class="toggle"><input type="text" value="2" name="sid[]">second</div>
    <div id="third" class="toggle"><input type="text" value="3" name="sid[]">third</div>
    <div id="forth" class="toggle"><input type="text" value="4" name="sid[]">forth</div>
    <div id="fifth" class="toggle"><input type="text" value="5" name="sid[]">fifth</div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#add1").click(function() {
            $('.toggle:not(:visible)').first().show();
        });
        $("#remove").click(function() {
            $('.toggle:visible').last().hide();

        });
    });
```

**Here is my code** : [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siddhuphp/cxxy2dhh/4/)

Comment: Linke this http://jsfiddle.net/cxxy2dhh/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add `.find('input').val('');` after `.hide();`  to be

```
$('.toggle:visible').last().hide().find('input').val('');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/cxxy2dhh/5/)

Comment: Hi, Shall i know as well as how to remove ids also ?

Comment: @SiddhuSiddharthaRoy hi :) .. Id must be unique so you shouldn't use same Id for more than one element .. after that .. just let me know which Id you want to remove??

Answer (score 2):

try this code:-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#add1").click(function() {
            $('.toggle:not(:visible)').first().show();
        });
        $("#remove").click(function() {
         $('.toggle:visible').last().find(':input').val('');
            $('.toggle:visible').last().hide();


        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**hi now used** to **[.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)**  and **[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** as like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#add1").click(function() {
            $('.toggle:not(:visible)').first().show();
        });
        $("#remove").click(function() {
            var valNon = $('.toggle:visible').last().hide();
               valNon.find('input').val(''); // add this line   

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#add1").click(function() {
            $('.toggle:not(:visible)').first().show();
        });
        $("#remove").click(function() {
           $('.toggle:visible').last().hide().find('input').val('');
        });
    });
```

[Jsfiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/cxxy2dhh/10/)